There is transparency in the edit mode
After exiting x-ray, transparency is maintained in edit mode. How to remove it?

What is the Clip Start and Clip End of the viewport ? Try decreasing End and/or increasing Start.

This ^^. In addition, do you have unapplied scale? What is your object dimension (shown next to the scale in the sidebar while in object mode)?

Just disable X-Ray option.
It's located in the top right corner of viewport area :


x-ray is disabled
